# Matching non commented pattern in eclipse

Tags: regex, eclipse, perl

I am having troubles with a regex syntax.

I want to match all occurrences of a certain word followed by a number, but exclude lines which are commented.

Comments are (multiple) `#` or `##` or `###` ...

Examples:

```
#This is a comment  <- no match

#This is a comment myword 8 <- no match

my $var = 'myword 12'; <- match

my $var2 = 'myword'; <- no match
```

Until now I have
**orignal pattern:** `^[^(\#+)](.*?)(myword \d+)(.*?)$`
**new pattern:** `^([^\#]*?)(myword\s+\d+)(.*?)$`

Which should match lines which do no begin with one or more `#`, followed by something, then the word number combination I am searching for and finally something.

It would perhaps be good to match also parts of lines if the comment does not begin at the beginning of the line.

```
my  $var3 = 'test';#myword 8 <- no match
```

What am I doing wrong?

I want to use it in Eclipse's file search (with Perl epic module).

**Edit:** The new pattern I got does no return false matches, but it return multiple the line which includes `myword` **and** several lines before that line. And I'm not sure it returns all matches.

Answer (score 3):

Note that `[]` are character classes. You cannot use quantifiers in there. They are like the `.` – matches any character given in there. The dot itself, or a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), can then be quantified.

In your example, `[^(#+)]` would match *everything except `(`,`)`, `+`, and* depending on the flavour (I guess) *`#` and `\`.*

So what you want here is to match a line that starts with any character except for a `#`. (I think.)

A problem is that the `#` might occur in a string where it is not a comment. (Regarding comments not starting at the beginning of the line.)

Comment: You are right with the wrong usage of `[]`. I don't think that in my case there is any use of # in a string where it is **not** a comment. And even if there would be any, I could neglect those cases.

Answer (score 2):

Re: comments not at the beginning of the string.

To do this **right** (e.g. not to miss any valid matches) you pretty much have to parse a file's specific programming language's grammar properly, so you can't do this (easily, or even at all) with a RegEx.

If you don't, you risk missing valid search hits that follow a "#" used in a context other than comment start - as an example common to pretty much any language, after a string `"this is my #hash"`.

It's even worse in Perl where "#" can also appear as a regex delimiter, as a `$#myArr` (index of the last element of an array), or - joy of joys - as a valid character in an identifyer name!

Comment: As I commented on Simon's answer I don't think there is any use of `#` other than for comments, and even it would be the case I could neglect those cases. I is not bad to miss some **right** matches, I just want to eliminate most **false** (aka. comments) matches.

Comment: @Pit - that depends on your purpose. 90+% of my code search like that, it's a LOT worse to miss a valid match than to have 10 false positives :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, if You are aware of these problems and still want to use regexp to extract the content. Something like this may be useful:

```
^[^\#].[^\n\#]+myword\s\d+.[$;]+
```

This is a little bit complex but I hope it will works for You.
For me this matches as below:

```
my $var = 'myword 12'; <- match
my $var = 'myword 17'; <- match
my $var2 = 'myword'; <- no match
my $var = 'myword 9'; #'myword 17'; <- partly match
my $var = 'myword 8'; ##'myword 127'; <- partly match
my $var = ;#'myword 17'; <- no match
#my $var = 'myword 13'; <- no match
##my $var2 = 'myword 14'; <- no match
```

Comment: This does not work for me; Maybe something was lost when copying the pattern? The first 6 characters being **bold** could indicate this.

Comment: I fixed the above expression. The tests I conducted in the Kodos, which is suitable for Python, although regexp should also work for perl.

Comment: Doesn't work either. What should the '[$;]+' do? Only match if either end of line is reached or command was ended?